# Android Phonegap Date Picker is not working in other devices except 4.2 O.S devices

Tags: android, phonegap-plugins

I am implementing the datepicker for android using phonegap 2.4.

The Date Picker is not working in other devices except android 4.2 os devices.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I am using cordova 2.5 and everything works fine. Can you post some code ?